# Dowload images while I browse site

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, wget, seleniumwire

**Goal:** Collect all the images from a site as I browse.

**I've tried:**

requests and wget don't work even with cookies set and all headers changed to mimic Firefox.

Firefox cache has the images, but they all have a random string as the name. I need logical names to sort them.

selenium-wire is very close to working. When I do driver.get(), driver.requests gives me all the requests as expected which can then be saved. The problem is when I click buttons on the site, the new requests do not get added to driver.requests. I tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    # browse site
    for request in driver.requests:
        if request.response:
            if "image/jpeg" in request.response.headers['Content-Type']:
                with open(request.url, 'wb') as f:
                    request.response.body
```

Comment: Can you add the URL you are trying to scrape?